# Entity Query from comment not working

Tags: entities, comments, database

I tried using entityquery for comment by nid but its not working here is my code :

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
    $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'comment')
    ->entityCondition('entity_id', 257, '=')
    ->addMetaData('account', user_load(1));
```

and also I tried changing to `nid` but still its showing all the comments instead of by specific `nid`:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
    $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'comment')
    ->entityCondition('nid', 257, '=')
    ->addMetaData('account', user_load(1));
```

can someone tell me I am doing anything wrong?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nid` is a property of the comment entity, so try:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'comment')
    ->propertyCondition('nid', 257)
    ->addMetaData('account', user_load(1));
```

Comment: you rock!! it solves my problem in a blast! :)